# Updating only ID's with the latest date SQL (2 of 6)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables:

[image: Table 1]

and:

[image: Table 2]

And I formulated this query:

```
Update Table 1 
SET DY_H_ID = ( 

    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM Table 2
    WHERE H_DateTime <= DY_Date 
    AND H_IDX = DY_IDX 
    AND H_HA_ID = 7 
    AND H_HSA_ID = 19 
    AND H_Description LIKE 'Diary item added for :%'

) 
WHERE DY_H_ID IS NULL AND DY_IDX IS NOT NULL
```

which results in this:

[image: Table 1 after Update]

However, this query updates all 6 rows.  I need to update only the two rows with the latest date, that would be `'2013-08-29 15:00:00.000'`.  That would mean only 2 of the 6 records would be updated and the other 4 would remain NULL.

How can I do this by adding to the above query?  I know this might not be ideal but there is no option but to do something like this.  What I don't understand is how do you select only the latest dates without hardcoding it.  This data can change and it won't always be the same dates etc.

Comment: What version of `sql-server` are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 1 
SET    DY_H_ID = (SELECT Max(ID) 
                  FROM   TABLE 2 
                  WHERE  H_DATETIME <= DY_DATE 
                         AND H_IDX = DY_IDX 
                         AND H_HA_ID = 7 
                         AND H_HSA_ID = 19 
                         AND H_DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Diary item added for :%') 
WHERE  DY_H_ID IS NULL 
       AND DY_IDX IS NOT NULL 
       AND DY_DATE = (SELECT Max(DY_DATE) 
                      FROM   TABLE1)
```

Comment: Excellent, this works perfect @Gidil.  That's why I am a SQL noob, haha.  Think you were first, so I will mark as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another condition to where:

```
Update Table 1 
SET DY_H_ID = ( 

    SELECT MAX(ID) 
    FROM Table 2
    WHERE H_DateTime <= DY_Date 
    AND H_IDX = DY_IDX 
    AND H_HA_ID = 7 
    AND H_HSA_ID = 19 
    AND H_Description LIKE 'Diary item added for :%'

) 
WHERE DY_H_ID IS NULL AND DY_IDX IS NOT NULL
and DY_Date = (select max(DY_Date) from Table 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `CTE`, compatible with `SQL-Server-2005` or later

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT H_IDX, MAX(ID) MaxID
    FROM Table2
    WHERE H_HA_ID = 7 
          AND H_HSA_ID = 19 
          AND H_Description LIKE 'Diary item added for :%'
    GROUP BY H_IDX
)
Update Table1 
SET DY_H_ID = MaxID
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN CTE ON cte.H_IDX = DY_IDX
WHERE DY_H_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This works great if I add the additional Condition in the WHERE clause.  Thanks @Luis LL

Comment: May I ask @Luis LL, if this UPDATE statement is run over let's say 1 000 000 records, will there be any performance improvements using the cte approach?  Is this better practice and cleaner than using other approaches, or why did you go with cte from the beginning?

Comment: not necessary, in some cases will be very efficient, there are many cases in which the CTE's _pre-fetch_ can really improve performance, in some others it will not affect. there is a third way to try which is using a inner join (`the CTE query`) and it also can perform better. There are many different factors, like indexes, memory, statistics, number of rows in each table, etc to give an absolute response

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.  I have read something about using them for recursion etc. as well which can be quite good.

Comment: well that is another great use for CTE, in the case above, I used it for simplicity, since I don't like the syntax `SELECT [mycolumns] FROM (SELECT ...) MyTable`. Go on reading about CTEs and good luck!